# What is the Formula For Assigning Position depending uppon percentage in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel

i need to set position in position column depending upon percentage column.
i also have asap utilities. Kindly share formula for this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the Rank() function.

As in

```
=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$10)
```

starting in D2 and copied down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(COUNIF(OFFSET(A$1,,,ROW(A$1:A$10)-ROW(A$1)1),A$1:a$10)+1)*(A$1:A$10>=A1))
```

use attributes according to your need.